Keycloak duplicate session issue
I have two Applications. On running on
example.com and another running on example.com/insurance/
I am using Keycloak IDP. The application running on /microinsurance/ is an Angular app 17.
In keycloak we have this configuration for session limit.

If user logs into the system and and visits /insurance  on another new tab then I am getting a duplicate session error from IDP although I am using the same browser and session.
Here's how I configured Keycloak on angular APP.
export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config: {
            url: KEYCLOAK_ISSUER_URL,
            realm: KEYCLOAK_REALM,
            clientId: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
          },
          initOptions: {
            checkLoginIframe: true,
            onLoad: 'login-required',
          },
          bearerExcludedUrls: [BEARER_EXCLUDE_URL]
        });
        resolve('Success');
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
}

Is there anything I am missing to do on the front end? How can I fix the duplicate session problem?

I'm pretty sure you'll need to run those applications on different domains. Try insurance.example.com instead.

Btw, avoid the Promise constructor antipattern and never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise!

@Bergi hi, actually  we do have another  react application which is an react app thats running on /otc, and that is working fine.
